# How to force windows application to run in 720p resolution and 16:9 ratio

Tags: video, resolution, screen-recorder

I have a 4k laptop that also set to 4k resolution, however I need to record a windowed game with 720p max resolution in 16:9 screen ratio. My desktop is not powerful enough to run it in larger resolution while also recording it. Is there a way or an additional app that can force another app to run within certain resolution and ratio? For now, I try to resize the windows myself. But, this result in screen that sometime larger or lower than 16:9.
The game I recorded was Minecraft For Windows 10 and recorded using XBox Companion app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free key-remapping product
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
can resize a window to an exact size.

The following AutoHotkey script will resize the currently active window to
1280×720 pixels when <kbd>F9</kbd> is pressed:

```
F9::WinMove, A, ,,, 1280,720
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

To use another key than <kbd>F9</kbd>, see the AutoHotKey
[List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).